How to measure the economic activity of a province?
I live in Canada.
I know that the TSX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Stock_Exchange) tracks the financial performance of the top companies in Canada. Naively, I would think that when the TSX drops, economic conditions (e.g. employment, inflation) in Canada worsen - and when the TSX is stable/high, the economic conditions in Canada improve.
I am just wondering - is there some type of stock/economic indicator which can allow me to gauge the economic health of different provinces in Canada (e.g. Ontario, Manitoba) at different time periods? I know that I can use inflation/CPI data from the internet (monthly level) ... but I was wondering if there is something available on a daily level (like TSX) which can give a rough indication of the financial health of different provinces at different times?
Does such a thing exist?

To gauge economic activity of a province you can use provincial real GDP per capita. that is a standard measure of economic activity in economics.
CPI or inflation doesn’t actually measure economic activity or health of an economy. Inflation can be high when economy is growing rapidly or when economy is in depression and vice versa.
I don’t think there is any reliable indicator of economic activity that would be published on daily level.
For high frequency measures of economic activity people in the field use proxies such as for example how many trucks ride the highways (e.g. see Lourenco and Rua, 2021 for some examples).
Also stock exchange indices don’t really track performance per se but rather peoples’s expectations of future performance.
